# Custom JComponent Not Being Added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm having a bit of a stickler with what I thought was quite a simple problem.

I have a custom JComponent `Ball` that is nothing more than a simple oval. I'm trying to add the ball to a JPanel which I have set as the JFrame's default content pane (via frame.setContentPane(mainPanel)). Along with the ball, I have two other components of class `Paddle`, another custom JComponent I have created. Oddly, the paddles can be added just fine.

The panel in question uses, on purpose, absolute layout to position the elements, since this was supposed to be a simple recreation of the Pong game.

I ran a simple test after adding the ball and both paddles to the JPanel, and found that the array of Components returned only listed two: the paddles. The full code adding all of them and initializing the JPanel and JFrame is as follows:

```
public Pong()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Pong");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainPanel = new JPanel(null);

    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    player = new Paddle(20, 100);
    enemy = new Paddle(20, 100);
    ball = new Ball(5, Color.GREEN);

    mainPanel.add(player);
    mainPanel.add(enemy);
    mainPanel.add(ball);
    enemy.setColor(Color.RED);

    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = screen.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2;
    int y = screen.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2;
    frame.setLocation(x, y);

    mainPanel.addKeyListener(mc);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    mainPanel.repaint();

    x = mainPanel.getWidth()/2 - ball.getWidth()/2;
    y = mainPanel.getHeight()/2 - ball.getHeight()/2;
    System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
    ball.setLocation(x, y);

    x = 0;
    y = mainPanel.getHeight()/2 - player.getHeight()/2;
    System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
    player.setLocation(x, y);

    x = mainPanel.getWidth() - enemy.getWidth();
    y = mainPanel.getHeight()/2 - enemy.getHeight()/2;
    System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
    enemy.setLocation(x, y);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mainPanel.getComponents()));

    mainPanel.repaint();

    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mainPanel.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    dm.start();
    mainPanel.requestFocus();
}
```

The code for the ball is as follows [**Note:** The ball is private because it is an inner class of class `Pong`, which does not extend anything]:

```
private class Ball extends JComponent
{
    private int radius;
    private Color color;

    public Ball(int size, Color c)
    {
        if(size > 0)
            radius = size;
        else
            radius = 1;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(radius, radius));
        color = c;
    }

    public Ball(int size)
    {
        this(size, Color.RED);
    }

    //Getters and Setters...

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

This isn't the first time I've encountered this problem when working on projects, and it always seems to occur when I'm using custom JComponents along with absolute positioning on a JPanel, although in still other projects, I don't seem to have a problem with this. It's probably something very simple that I'm overlooking, but I can't think of what it is, for the life of me. Any answers to this would be greatly appreciated.

If absolutely necessary, [all the lines of code for this project can be found here](http://pastebin.com/BKervdxt) (Just over 300 lines total).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I forgot to mention: mc and dc are a MoveManager and DisplayManager respectively, but should have no bearing on the display of the ball. Just to clear up those unknown variables.

Comment: You forgot to call `super.paintComponent(g)` within `Ball.paintComponent()`.

Comment: I didn't do that for the paddles, either, though. I'll fix that, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add components to a panel using a null layout then you are responsible for setting the `size` and `location` of the component.

If you don't set the size then it will be zero and so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: +1. OP should replace `setPreferredSize` by `setSize` within `Ball` class constructor. Inspecting a little at [OP's code](http://pastebin.com/BKervdxt) he/she has overridden (perhaps unknowingly) `getHeight` and `getWidth` methods in `Paddle` class and that's why this one is painted but `Ball` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is silly and simple.

Add the following call the constructor and `setRadius` method in your Ball class:

```
this.setSize(new Dimension(radius, radius));
```

And all should be well. Basically, preferred size isn't enforced, so be explicit: set the size. Otherwise, when repainting the JPanel, this component has size of 0 and is skipped.

(Edited based on comment, thanks, my Swing is rusty)

Comment: Don't override those methods. You should be using the setSize(...) or setBounds(...) method.

Comment: Thanks, edited. My Swing is rusty, forgot that was best practice.